# Synchronize MySQL and express server

Tags: node.js

This is my very first challenge with NodeJS and I think that I'm little bit got lost with all the callbacks and asynchronous stuff.

I have a server, using express and want that one of the requests will query the DB and return the results.

With any other language, I would write a function that do so, return the value and everything will be good.
My code looks like that:

```
function queryDB(daysAgo){
    var connection = mysql.createConnection({
     host: "dbadress.com",
     user: "dbuser",
     password: "dbpassword",
     database: "db"
 });
    var returnValue;

    sqlQuery = "select * from db.database where time_created > now() - interval " + daysAgo + " day"
    connection.query(sqlQuery, function(error, results, fields){
       if (error) throw error;
        returnValue= results[0];
    });
    return returnValue;

}

app.get('/', function (req, res){
    var daysAgo = req.query.days_ago;
    var returnValue = queryMICE(daysAgo);
    res.send("Days Ago: '+ daysAgo + '\nTargeted URL: ' + returnValue);
});
```

And that of course return `undefined` because of the `queryDB` function is not synchronous.

Will be happy to get a short intro about the callbacks in NodeJS and example how should I write this one to return the query value.

Thanks ahead!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of having your *queryDB* return a value, pass a callback function to it that receives the return value, like this:

```
function queryDB(daysAgo, callback) {
    var connection = mysql.createConnection({
        host: "dbadress.com",
        user: "dbuser",
        password: "dbpassword",
        database: "db"
    });

    sqlQuery = "select * from db.database where time_created > now() - interval " + daysAgo + " day";
    connection.query(sqlQuery, function (error, results, fields) {
        if (error) {
            throw error;
        }
        callback(results[0]);
    });
}

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    var daysAgo = req.query.days_ago;
    queryDB(daysAgo, returnValue => res.send("Days Ago: " + daysAgo + '\nTargeted URL: ' + returnValue));
});
```

As a side note: it is **extremeley dangerous** to create an SQL query by concatenating a request parameter. You should **never** use code like this in production, but that's another story. Google for “SQL injection” to find out more.

Comment: In this line `queryMICE(daysAgo, returnValue => res.send("Days Ago: '+ daysAgo + '\nTargeted URL: ' + returnValue));` can you please explain shortly what the `=>` stands for?

Comment: That's an arrow function, you can also write it like this: `queryMICE(daysAgo, function (returnValue) { res.send("Days Ago: " + daysAgo + '\nTargeted URL: ' + returnValue); });`

Comment: Thanks! Does `daysAgo` will be still in the scope of the function?

Comment: Yes, is `daysAgo` will be in the scope of the callback function.